# How to write functional tests for a slack app

Tags: slack, functional-testing

We have a slack app. The slack app has a lot of functionalities.
We have used Sprint boot as the backend. We did not use any slack app library and all  slack events are listened at our backend by configuring the endpoint(web-hook) in slack admin portal.

**We are using slack api's to send messages/update messages to slack app. And also other functionalities, all by hitting slack endpoints**

*Similar endpoints(as per this document)* - https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending

Now since the app's functionality is increasing day by day, manual testing of all app functionalities is becoming hard and introducing fatigue and decreasing our productivity.

I would like to build a suit of functional tests which would run after/before every new release of our code.

*Could you guide how to achieve this* . We would like to use java to write these functional tests.